# Pass Value javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, parameter-passing

When I select a date that I memorize in the selected variable, when I press the Submit button, I would like to print the value of the js variable in the php file. How can I do?
At the time php returns indefinded index 'name'

**Index File**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( function() {

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',minDate:0 });


$("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
var selected = $(this).val();
$.get('Prenota.php', {getname: selected});

console.log(selected, "Hello, world!");
});
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<form action ="Prenota.php" method="GET"> <input type="sumbit" name="upload" 
value ="Prenota">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
 $variable = $_GET['name'];
 echo ($variable)
 ?>
```

Comment: It is `$_GET['getname']`

Comment: Ah, not even a duplicate, it's a typo close!

Comment: not works Matei

Comment: It's type "submit". You have a typo. The valid syntax would be 
`<input type="submit" name="upload" 
value ="Prenota">`